# Adding action listener to Image

Tags: java, image, swing, listener

```
Image img= Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("icon.png");
g.drawImage(img,(int)x,(int)y,disp);
```

I want to add action listener to this image and handle the events occurred . How can i do it?

Comment: What all events you want??? and what is `g`???

Answer (score 4):

Draw `image/icon` on `JButton` and attach the `ActionListener` instance to it (Button).

Comment: But the problem is that in one window we need to display multiple images(one icon for each of the nodes in a sensor network),and for each of the icon we need action listener

Comment: and the button needs to be displayed at particular coordinates.

Comment: @KiranB - You have rephrase your post and put necessary code and explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot add `ActionListener` directly to an Image. You have to use it in UI component like Button which has `ActionListener`.

Comment: But the problem is that in one window we need to display multiple images(one icon for each of the nodes in a sensor network),and for each of the icon we need action listener, and the button needs to be displayed at particular coordinates

Answer (score -1):

Get that image onto a JLabel and attach ActionListener to it.

```
BufferedImage myPicture2 = ImageIO.read(filepath);
JLabel lbl= new JLabel();
lblPic.setIcon(new ImageIcon(myPicture2));
```

Comment: -1, You can't add an action listener to a `JLabel` instance. But what you can add is a `MouseListener`, but that being said, why not use a `JButton` instead?

Comment: oopS! I meant that only. But no probs as I got a -1.

Comment: But the problem is that in one window we need to display multiple images(one icon for each of the nodes in a sensor network),and for each of the icon we need action listener, and the button needs to be displayed at particular coordinates